# How can I solve [object Promise] on vue?

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

My code like this :

```
<v-row dense>
    <v-col
        v-for="(item, i) in items"
        :key="i"
        cols="12"
        >
        <v-card
            dark
        >
            <div class="d-flex flex-no-wrap justify-space-between">
            <div>
                <v-card-title
                class="headline"
                v-text="item.doctor"
                ></v-card-title>

                <v-card-subtitle v-text="item.hospital"></v-card-subtitle>
                <v-card-subtitle>{{available(item.doctorId, item.hospitalId)}}</v-card-subtitle>
            </div>

            <v-avatar
                class="ma-3"
                size="125"
                tile
            >
                <v-img :src="item.src"></v-img>
            </v-avatar>
            </div>
        </v-card>
    </v-col>
</v-row>

  methods: {
    // available (doctorId, hospitalId) {
    available: async function (doctorId, hospitalId) {
      let fromDate = moment()
      let toDate = moment().add(2, 'days')

      while (fromDate <= toDate) {

        const payload = {
          hospitalId: hospitalId,
          doctorId: doctorId,
          date: fromDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        }

        // this is async/ajax to call api by vuex store
        // await this.checkAvailibility(payload)

        // if (this.availibility.items.length > 0) {
          if(fromDate.diff(moment(), 'days') == 0) {
            return `<v-icon class="mr-2" color="success">check_circle</v-icon>Available Today`
          }
          else if(fromDate.diff(moment(), 'days') == 1)
            return `<v-icon>check_circle</v-icon>Available Tomorrow`
          else
            return `<v-icon>check_circle</v-icon>Available ${fromDate}`
        // } 

        fromDate = fromDate.add(1, 'days')
      }
    },
  },
```

Demo and full code like this :

https://codepen.io/trendingnews/pen/vYENWqR?editors=1010

This error might occur because I use `async`. But I need that. Because I want to call ajax via vuex store

How can I solve this problem without remove async?

Note :

`this.availibility.items.length` is used to check whether a doctor is available or not on a certain day. if greater than 0 means it is available

I commented that because it called vuex store

Comment: I don't think you can use `async` function in the template. Generally you load data asynchronously in the `created` lifecycle, update your data, which will then update your template.

Comment: @Psidom I can use `async`. I use async to wait for the async / ajax process to finish. if it's finished, it will update the data in the template

Comment: But you are directly using `async` function in the template as `{{available(item.doctorId, item.hospitalId)}}` without `await`ing it, do you expect it returns data?

Comment: @Psidom  if i don't use `await`, it will error. because it will immediately run the statement below. so I have to use `await` to wait for the `async` process to finish. I have tried it. so i did this. hope you understand. Yeah, I expect it return data

Comment: I don't think you get what I mean. You can use `async` / `await` in javascript, and you can declare a method as `async`, but you can't call an `async` function from the template, i.e. inside `<template></template>`, because it's not javascript. Check this post. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-async-method-result-in-template/36505/5

Comment: @Psidom Actually I want to call the method in `created` or `mounted`. But I have a problem. I can't send doctorId and hospitalId

Comment: if `items` already exist when the component is loaded, one way to do it in `created` is looping through `items` where you can access doctorId and hospitalId, use `Vue.set` ([the reason to use Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)) to update each `item` with an availability attribute, in this way you can directly access the availability in UI by doing `item.availability` instead of `available(item.doctorId, item.hospitalId)` for instance.

Comment: @Psidom Actual items taken from the API. and before that I did what you said. I put availability in the item. but I want to change that. because it makes the process take so long. I want availability called when it appears on the laptop screen. otherwise it's not called. this is to speed up the process of displaying data listings

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://codepen.io/leopsidom/pen/ZEYbvRK?editors=1010

Comment: @Psidom Actually I mean like this : for example there are 10 doctor's data. that appears on the laptop screen there are 3 doctors data (doctor A, doctor B, doctor C). it will call the availbale method to check whether or not the doctor is available. when the user scrolls down there is doctor D, doctor E, doctor F. it will call the availbale method to check whether the doctor is available or not. so available each doctor is called when the doctor appears on the laptop screen. I did this to speed up the process of displaying data